# Format for ID of YouTube video

Tags: youtube, url

Every YouTube video has a unique ID which can be used to get at it. For example, the video at `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aN46pEO_jX8` has the id `aN46pEO_jX8`.

After some observation, it looks to me like these IDs obey the following two rules:

- Exactly 11 characters
- Allowed symbols: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, and _

I want to know:

1. Whether these two rules are both always correct.
2. If there are any other rules that are important to follow.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to the Youtube [2.0 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3avideoid) and [3.0 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), the **videoId** is a string, nothing is specified about the current set of characters used...

About the 11 characters length, a [post from a Youtube API Team](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/oAztQ3f1tcM) say :

> I don't see anywhere in the documentation where we officially commit 
>   to a standard length of 11 characters for YouTube video ids. It's one 
>   of those things where we have a current implementation, and it may 
>   stay that way indefinitely. But we're not offering any official 
>   commitment to that, so proceed at your own risk.

And last but not least, [another post clarify](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/youtube-api-gdata/maM-h-zKPZc/PJDlDWv77TEJ) (or not) the format :

> We don't make any public guarantees about the format for video ids.
>   While they're currently 11 character strings that contain letters,
>   numbers and some punctuation, I wouldn't recommend hardcoding that
>   into your application (unless you have an easy way of changing it in
>   the future).

The Youtube team seems to prefer to directly ask Youtube server if the Video_ID is correct or not (refer to an existing video) :

> If you need to validate that random user input corresponds to a valid
>   video id, I'd recommend doing an empirical test. Attempt to access
>
> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID
>
> If you get a 200 response, then VIDEO_ID is valid. If you get a
>   non-200 response, you have an invalid id. There are some edge cases
>   for newly uploaded videos or private videos, but for most purposes I'd
>   assume that would be okay.

Comment: This is a great answer, and gave me all the info I needed! Thank you!

Comment: This returns a HTTP 410 gone now. Any ideas as to what the new URL should be to verify this now?

Comment: To verify the video id: just get html page from youtube and verify that meta canonical link have the same id that you specified.

Answer (score 135):

#### Summary

---

YouTube **videoId** and **channelId** identifiers are single integer values represented in a slightly mod­ified version of [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). One difference versus the [IETF RFC4648 recommendations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) is the substitution of two characters in the encoding alphabet:

```
 Payload  ASCII/Unicode      Base64     YouTube
 -------  -------------     ---------  ---------
  0...25  \x41 ... \x5A     'A'...'Z'  'A'...'Z'
 26...51  \x61 ... \x7A     'a'...'z'  'a'...'z'
 52...61  \x30 ... \x39     '0'...'9'  '0'...'9'
    62    \x2F vs. \x2D  →   '/' (2F)   '-' (2D)
    63    \x2B vs. \x5F  →   '+' (2B)   '_' (5F)
```

The substitution is likely due to the fact that, for some reason [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.4) selected two characters that already had prominent and well-established functions in URLs.<sup>[note 1.]</sup> Obviously, for the usage under discussion here, that particular complication was best avoided.

Another difference from the official specification is that **YouTube** identifiers do not use the `=` padding character; it's not necessary because the encoded lengths expected per respective de­coded integer size are fixed and known (11 and 22 encoded 'digits' for 64 and 128 bits, respec­tively).

With one minor exception (explained below), the full details of the Base64 mapping can be inferred from publicly accessible data. It turns out that, with no proprietary knowledge—and essentially no guesswork—it *must* be the case that the **Base64** scheme used in the **videoId** and **channelId** strings is as follows:

```
    ——₀————₁————₂————₃————₄————₅————₆————₇————₈————₉———₁₀———₁₁———₁₂———₁₃———₁₄———₁₅—
     00ᴴ  01ᴴ  02ᴴ  03ᴴ  04ᴴ  05ᴴ  06ᴴ  07ᴴ  08ᴴ  09ᴴ  0Aᴴ  0Bᴴ  0Cᴴ  0Dᴴ  0Eᴴ  0Fᴴ
00→ 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P

    —₁₆———₁₇———₁₈———₁₉———₂₀———₂₁———₂₂———₂₃———₂₄———₂₅———₂₆———₂₇———₂₈———₂₉———₃₀———₃₁—
     10ᴴ  11ᴴ  12ᴴ  13ᴴ  14ᴴ  15ᴴ  16ᴴ  17ᴴ  18ᴴ  19ᴴ  1Aᴴ  1Bᴴ  1Cᴴ  1Dᴴ  1Eᴴ  1Fᴴ
01→ 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
      Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z    a    b    c    d    e    f

    —₃₂———₃₃———₃₄———₃₅———₃₆———₃₇———₃₈———₃₉———₄₀———₄₁———₄₂———₄₃———₄₄———₄₅———₄₆———₄₇—
     20ᴴ  21ᴴ  22ᴴ  23ᴴ  24ᴴ  25ᴴ  26ᴴ  27ᴴ  28ᴴ  29ᴴ  2Aᴴ  2Bᴴ  2Cᴴ  2Dᴴ  2Eᴴ  2Fᴴ
10→ 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
      g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n    o    p    q    r    s    t    u    v

    —₄₈———₄₉———₅₀———₅₁———₅₂———₅₃———₅₄———₅₅———₅₆———₅₇———₅₈———₅₉———₆₀———₆₁———₆₂———₆₃—
     30ᴴ  31ᴴ  32ᴴ  33ᴴ  34ᴴ  35ᴴ  36ᴴ  37ᴴ  38ᴴ  39ᴴ  3Aᴴ  3Bᴴ  3Cᴴ  3Dᴴ  3Eᴴ  3Fᴴ
11→ 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
      w    x    y    z    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    -    _
```

The analysis below also establishes further non-obvious constraints on the expressed form of the **videoId** and **channelId** identifiers. This (presumably novel) result is summarized by the following two [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which I provide here for those who aren't interested in reading the formal analysis that follows.

#### RegEx

---

```
videoId:    [0-9A-Za-z_-]{10}[048AEIMQUYcgkosw]

channelId:  [0-9A-Za-z_-]{21}[AQgw]
```

#### Range and Distribution

---

When a new item is created, YouTube permanently assigns it an unused ID value of the appropriate type. Initial values appear to be randomly selected with a strongly uniform distribution across the entire bitness range (64- or 128-bit), allowing for up to 2⁶⁴ (18​ quintillion) or 2¹²⁸ (3.4 × 10³⁸) ID values respectively. No metadata is encoded; for example, a **videoId** value contains no information about what channel it comes from. It is likely that ID values of cancelled items are never reused or recycled. It also seems likely that certain ID values are excluded from ever being issued; for example, where the Base64 encoding happens to contain the spelling of a suggestive word in some [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language).

#### Discussion

---

The reason to believe that Base64 is being used is that, when we assume standard integer sizes of 64 and 128 bits for the encoder input, Base64 *predicts the unusual character lengths* (11 and 22 characters) *of the YouTube **channelId** and **videoId** identifiers exactly*. Furthermore, remainders calculated as per Base64 perfectly explain the observed distributional variation found in the *l̲a̲s̲t̲ c̲h̲a̲r̲a̲c̲t̲e̲r̲* of each type of identifier string. Discussion of these points follows.

In both cases, the binary "data" that gets Base64-encoded is a *s̲i̲n̲gl̲e̲ i̲n̲t̲e̲ge̲r̲*, either **64** or **128** bits, for (respectively) **videoId** vs. **channelId**. Accordingly, by using a Base64 decoder, a single integer can be recovered from the respective *s̲t̲r̲i̲n̲g i̲d̲e̲n̲t̲i̲f̲i̲e̲r̲*. It can be quite useful to do this because, while each integer id contains exactly the same information as the Base64 string—and also allows the string to be recreated at any time—when compared to Base64 strings stored as Unicode, the binary representation is:

- 63% smaller,
- has the (obviously maximal) bit-density of 100%,
- aligns in memory better,
- sorts and hashes faster, and, perhaps most importantly,
- eliminates **false collisions** between identifiers that differ only in [orthographic case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case).

This last problem, though extremely improbable numerically, nevertheless cannot be ruled out when Base64 IDs are treated as case-insensitive, as some filesystems do (e.g. [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), dating back to [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS)). That's kinda important: if you're using a **videoId** / **channelId** string as part of a Windows/‌NTFS filename, there's a vanishingly miniscule—*but nevertheless non-zero*—chance of filename collisions due to those filesystems deploying case-insensitive path and file naming.

If you're worried about the extremely remote possibility of filename collisions, one way to formally eliminate it would be to re-encode the decoded integers—still obtained as described in this article—into either a base-10 (decimal) or (thence case-agnostic) hexadecimal representation, for use in path or file names on such filesystems.<sup>[note 2.]</sup> In this approach, the 64-bit **videoId** would need 20 decimal digits `[0-9]` or 8 hex digits `[0-9,A-F]` (*vs.* 11 Base64 digits). The 128-bit **channelId** would require a maximum of 39 decimal digits or 16 hex digits (*vs.* 22 Base64 digits).

#### Analysis

---

You might have noticed above that I wrote that you can recover "*an*" integer from the exposed string value. Wouldn't this simply be the value that was originally encoded? The answer is almost certainly "yes" (and this section will discuss the supporting analysis in some detail). Note, however, that while we can be almost certain that the we are obtaining the exact same binary value recorded "internally" in YouTube's master vault, this fact is also quite certainly moot.

In other words, while the evidence shown in the sections below is convincing and perhaps in­ter­esting or satisfying as well, it also doesn't matter if it is wrong. As long as YouTube never exposes the so-called "correct" values *in binary form* somewhere/anywhere publicly, then decoded 64- or 128-bit values have no use except as an opaque identifying token, and any binary re-encoding used privately can't possibly matter.

The only only true requirements for the transform are *distinct encoding* (no two unique tokens collide) and perfect *reversibility* (decoding recovers the original token identity). All we really care about is ***lossless round-tripping*** of the original Base64 string. Since Base64 is lossless and reversible (as long as you always stick to the same alphabet mapping and [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) assumption for both encoding and decoding) it satisfies our purposes.

There *are* a few clues that can tell us about the "true" **Base64** mapping. The crux of the puzzle is that only certain mappings correctly predict the final-position characters that we observe, meaning the binary value for *only those characters* must have a certain number of LSB zeros. Heh. The mathematical details are specific to the each bit width, so I discuss the 64- and 128-bit identifiers separately in the next two sections.

Suffice it to say that, taken together with the overwhelmingly likely assumption that the alphabet and digit characters are mapped in ascending order, we can basically confirm the mapping to be what is shown in the tables above. The only remaining uncertainty about which the analysis below is math­ematically inconclusive concerns the mapping of the `-` and `_` characters for encoding **Base64** digits `62` and `63` (*i.e.*, respectively?).<sup>[note 3.]</sup>

#### videoId

---

The **videoId** identifier string encodes an 8-byte (64-bit) integer. Applying Base64-encoding to 8 bytes of data requires **11 characters**. However, since each Base64 character conveys exactly 6 bits (viz., 2⁶ equals 64), this allocation could actually hold up to `11 × 6 = 66` bits—a surplus of 2 bits over the 64 bits our payload needs. The excess bits are set to zero, which has the effect of excluding certain characters from ever appearing in the last position of the encoded string. In par­ticular, the **videoId** is guaranteed to always end with one of the following characters:

```
{ A, E, I, M, Q, U, Y, c, g, k, o, s, w, 0, 4, 8 }
```

Thus, the maximally-constrained regular expression (RegEx) for the **videoId** would be as follows:

```
[0-9A-Za-z_-]{10}[048AEIMQUYcgkosw]
```

#### channelId

---

The **channelId** (and some types of **playlistId**) strings are produced by Base64-encoding a 128-bit (16-byte) binary integer. This gives a 22-character string which can be prefixed with either `UC` to identify the channel itself, or with `UU` to identify a full playlist of the videos it contains. These 24-character prefixed strings are used in **URLs**. For example, the following two URLs pertain to the same channel, since they have the same 22-digit Base64 suffix (`K8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA`, shown in bold):

```
Channel URL:         https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA

Playlist URL:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA
```

Both of these URL formulations can be useful. For example, the playlist page includes information on the total number of videos in the channel,<sup>[see note 4.]</sup> a useful piece of information which other channel pages don't seem to expose.

Similar to the case with the 11-character **videoId**, calculation per Base64 assuming an 8-byte integer correctly predicts the obser­ved string length of **22-characters**. In this case, the output is capable of encoding `22 × 6 = 132` bits, a surplus of 4 bits, and those bits being zero ends up restricting m̲o̲s̲t̲ of the 64 alphabet symbols from appearing in the last position, with only 4 remaining eligible. We therefore know that the last char­ac­ter in a YouTube **channelId** string must be one of the following:

```
{ A, Q, g, w }
```

This gives us the maximally-constrained regular expression for a **channelId**:

```
[0-9A-Za-z_-]{21}[AQgw]
```

Remember, this regular expression describes the bare 22-character **channelID** value only, without any prefixes, slashes, separators, etc., that might be present in URLs, within HTML pages, and the other various uses. Indeed more generally, although the RegEx patterns I give here (and above) are mathematically minimal for identifier strings *in isolation*, they are still likely to generate a lot of false-positives (that is, incorrectly match spurious text) if used *as-is* without additional surrounding con­text. To avoid this problem in actual use, be sure to elaborate these regular expressions with as much of the expected adjacent or surrounding context as possible.

#### Implementation

---

For the **64-bit** (videoId) case, decoding to binary is trivial because you can use a `UInt64` (`ulong` in **C#**) to hold the resulting "native" binary value.

```
// Recover the unique 64-bit value from an 11-character videoID (native-endian)
//
// The method of padding shown here (i.e. 'b64pad') is provided to demonstrate the
// full and correct padding requirement for Base64 in general. For our cases:
//
//    videoId    →  11 chars  →  b64pad[11 % 3]  →  b64pad[2]  →  "="
//    channelId  →  22-chars  →  b64pad[22 % 3]  →  b64pad[1]  →  "=="
//
// Note however that, because it returns 'ulong', this function only works for videoId
// values, and the padding will always end up being "=". This is assumed in the revised
// version of this code given further below, by just hard-coding the value "=".

static ulong YtEnc_to_videoId(String ytId)
{
    String b64 = ytId.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/') + b64pad[ytId.Length % 3];

    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(Convert.FromBase64String(b64), 0);
}

static String[] b64pad = { "", "==", "=" };
```

For the case of the **128-bit** values, it's slightly trickier because, unless your compiler has an `__int128` representation, you'll have to figure out a way to store the whole thing and keep it [combobulated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/combobulate) as you pass it around. A simple value type (or [`System.Numerics.Vectors.Vector<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1), which manifests as a 128-bit SIMD hardware register, when available) will do the trick in .NET (not shown).

A final technical point concerns *endianness*. You might in fact want to intentionally choose  [big-endian](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Big-Endian.svg) for your binary interpretation, even though it's less common than [little-endian](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Little-Endian.svg) nowadays. The reason is that this is a case of dual views on the same value, such that the actual byte order is concomitantly exposed in the Base64 rendition. It's helpful and less confusing to keep the ***sort order*** consistent between the binary value and the (somewhat more) human-readable Base64 string, but the sort of the little-endian binary values is a non-trivial scramble of the desired ASCII/lexical sort.

Because of the irregular overlap between the 6-bit pattern and 8-bit bytes, there's no simple fix for the human-readable sorting problem once you encode to little-endian ID values (i.e. simply revers­ing the sort won't work). Instead, you have to plan ahead and reverse the bytes of each binary value *prior to decoding*, in other words, apply the *endianness* transform. So if you care about the alphabetical display matching the sorting of the binary values, you might want to alter the function shown above so that it decodes into ***big-endian*** `ulong` values instead. Here's that code:

```
// Recover the unique 64-bit value from an 11-character videoID (big-endian)

static ulong YtEnc_to_videoId(String ytId)
{
    ytId = ytId.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/') + "=";
    var a = Convert.FromBase64String(ytId);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)   // true for most computers nowadays
        Array.Reverse(a);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(a, 0);
}
```

---

**Notes**
**<sub>[ 1. ]</sub>**
As promised above, here is an excerpt from the [Base64 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.4) which discusses the con­sid­er­a­tions for selecting alphabet symbols. Individuals seeking to understand how the working group ultimately managed to [recommend](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-6) a character '`/`' which is fundamental to URL semantics—indeed one of a tiny few the citation itself identifies (*twice!*) as "particularly problematic"—may find the discus­sion somewhat unedifying, if not entirely bizarre:

> [**3.4. Choosing the Alphabet**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ea7.png)
> Different applications have different requirements on the characters in the alphabet. Here are a few requirements that determine which alphabet should be used:
>
> - Handled by humans. The characters "0" and "O" are easily confused, as are "1", "l", and "I".  In the base32 alphabet below, where 0 (zero) and 1 (one) are not present, a decoder may interpret 0 as O, and 1 as I or L depending on case.  (However, by default it should not; see previous section.)
> - Encoded into structures that mandate other requirements.  For
>   base 16 and base 32, this determines the use of upper- or lowercase alphabets.  For base 64, the non-alphanumeric characters (in particular, "/") may be problematic in file names and URLs.
> - Used as identifiers. Certain characters, notably "+" and "/" in the base 64 alphabet, are treated as word-breaks by legacy text search/index tools.
>
> There is no universally accepted alphabet that fulfills all the requirements.  For an example of a highly specialized variant, see [IMAP - [RFC 3501 5.1.3.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3)].  In this document, we document and name some currently used alphabets.

**<sub>[ 2. ]</sub>**
Alternatively, to solve the problem of using Base64-encoded ID strings as "as-is" components of file or path names on the NTFS filesystem, which is case-insensitive by default (and thus technically risks incorrectly conflating one or more unrelated ID values), it so happens that NTFS [can be configured with case-sensitive path/file naming](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem) on a per-volume basis. Enabling the non-default behavior may fix the problem described here, but is rarely recommended since it alters expectations for any/all the disparate applications that inspect or access the volume. If you're even considering this option, [read and understand this](http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/02/understanding-case-sensitivity-in-windows-obcaseinsensitive-file_case_sensitive_search/) first, and you'll probably change your mind.

**<sub>[ 3. ]</sub>**
As the analysis shows, it's because neither `-` nor `_` can ever appear as the *final character* of an ID that the small uncertainty remains.

**<sub>[ 4. ]</sub>**
I believe the total number of videos shown the channel playlist page takes into account an exclu­sion for videos which are restricted according to the geographical region of the HTTP client. This accounts for any discrepancy between the number of videos listed for the playlist vs. channel. (update - May 2021: The web page for a playlist now seems to include an alert message when one or more of its videos are "unavailable".)

Comment: That is some impressive detective work.

Comment: Holy guacamole, this answers deserves 1,000s of upvotes

Comment: YouTube channel IDs are now 24 chars long, not 22; e.g. UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg; source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube#answer-16326307

Comment: @evandrix Thanks for your note. The last paragraph of my post was meant to address this issue; I only discuss the *variable portion* of the ID string. There are prefixes for channel ID (can be for example **UC** or **UU**) which are not discussed in this post. If you have a prefixed value such as your example, the information I provde applies to the last 22 characters.

Comment: ok, thanks for your clarification :)

Comment: @evandrix In case you're still interested, I just updated the article itself to include information about the `UC` *vs.* `UU` **channelId** prefixes.

Comment: Bruh, this reply is so long it's probably longer than all of mine's added together!

Comment: @GlennSlayden great writeup! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GlennSlayden :D

Comment: When you join a comminuty just to upvote an answer.  Very useful writeup which helped, thanks.

Comment: Awesome detective work indeed. I was looking to see if there was some simple integer logic behind the youtube video ids (for a random video app) and this post was obviously the work of some hard hours of work. Well done and thanks.

Comment: [Section 5 of RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) specifically names the alphabet with minus and underscore as an URL-safe alternative alphabet. So it’s not really a difference to the RFC YouTube decided on, but they followed this alternative alphabet as described in there for the use case described in there.

Comment: FYI UInt64 is not required. Int64 (signed) is ok too. 
"Using a signed 64 bit integer for storing this identifier is safe."
[Twitter Docs Source](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet)